# Recoger un array JSON en un HTML procedente de PHP y mostrarlo en XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Estoy intentando recoger un bucle de PHP en una función XMLHttpRequest para mostrar un listado en un HTML.

```
$resulTiposTienda = ClaseTiposTienda::obtenerBucleTiposTienda();
$bucle_TiposTienda = $resulTiposTienda[0];
$contadorTiposTienda = count($bucle_TiposTienda);
foreach($bucle_TiposTienda as $itemTiposTienda):
  $myArr = array($itemTiposTienda['id_tipotienda'], $itemTiposTienda['nombre_tipotienda']);     
  $myJSON = json_encode($myArr);
  echo $myJSON;
endforeach;
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
["38501","Cosm\u00e9tica"]["38502","Calzado"]["38503","Textil"]["38504","Inform\u00e1tica"]["38505","Servicios"]["38506","Alimentaci\u00f3n"]["38507","Er\u00f3tica"]["38508","Artesan\u00eda"]["38509","Deporte"]["38510","Papeler\u00eda"]["38511","Arte"]["38512","Electrodom\u00e9sticos"]["38513","General"]["38514","M\u00fasica"]["38515","Herbolario"]["38516","Segunda mano"]["38517","Art\u00edculos Mascotas"]["38518","Mobiliario"]["38519","Automoci\u00f3n"]["38520","Regalos"]
```

Intento recoger ese resultado para mostrarlo en el div id

```
<div id="id_tipotienda"></div>
```

usando XMLHttpRequest y no me devuelve nada en la página.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("id_tipotienda").innerHTML = myObj;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "obtenerdatos.php", true);
```

Uso el document ready, la libreria jquery correctamente, etc... alguien sabría encontrar el/los fallos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado `JSON` no está bien formateado, te debería quedar algo así:

```
[  
   {  
      "id_tipotienda": "38501",
      "nombre_tipotienda": "Cosm\u00e9tica"
   },
   {  
      "id_tipotienda": "38502",
      "nombre_tipotienda": "Calzado"
   },
   {  
     "id_tipotienda": "38503",
     "nombre_tipotienda": "Textil"
   },

   ...

   {  
      "id_tipotienda": "38520",
      "nombre_tipotienda": "Regalos"
   }
]
```

Cambia esta línea de tu archivo `PHP` y agrégale una clave:

```
$myArr = array($itemTiposTienda['id_tipotienda'], $itemTiposTienda['nombre_tipotienda']);

$myArr = array("id_tipotienda" => $itemTiposTienda['id_tipotienda'], "nombre_tipotienda" => $itemTiposTienda['nombre_tipotienda']);
```

Teniendo eso, el código `javascript` que pones le faltaría sólo esta línea:

```
// Despues de esta
xmlhttp.open("GET", "obtenerdatos.php", true);    
xmlhttp.send(); //<-
```

Sin embargo esto te devolvería un resultado similiar a este:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ...
```

En este caso te sugiero unos cambio para que puedas visualizar la información de manera correcta así:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "obtenerdatos.php";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            visualizaArray(myArr);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function visualizaArray(arr) {
        var out = "";
        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += '<p><b>id tipo Tienda: </b>' + arr[i].id_tipotienda + '<br>' + 
            '<b>Nombre Tipo Tienda: </b>' + arr[i].nombre_tipotienda + '</p>';
        }
        document.getElementById("id_tipotienda").innerHTML = out;
    }
})
```

Espero que esto solucione tu problema, saludos.

Comment: No lo solucioné exactamente así, pero me sirvió de mucho tu respuesta, añado la solución definitiva.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente lo arreglé de la siguiente manera declarando [] y colocando el encode fuera del bucle.

```
     foreach($bucle_TiposTienda as $itemTiposTienda):
     if($contadorTiposTienda!=''){ 
         $myArr[]= array("id_tipotienda" => $itemTiposTienda['id_tipotienda'], "nombre_tipotienda" => $itemTiposTienda['nombre_tipotienda']);
     }
     endforeach;
     $myJSON = json_encode($myArr);
     echo $myJSON;
```

Gracias a la inestimable ayuda de @Fabian Faria en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/278831/6897) compuse la llamada así:

```
  $(document).ready(function (){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var out = "";
      var i;
      for(i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
         out += '<option value="' + myObj[i].id_tipotienda + '">'+myObj[i].nombre_tipotienda + '</option>';
        }
        document.getElementById("id_tipotienda").innerHTML = out;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "obtenerdatos.worker.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    });
```